# How to connect Emulator with External storage device?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am beginner in android. I start with android emulator and then also used to SD Card folders and files. It's working fine. I need to connect with emulator and external storage device (Pen Drive) to access those Pen Drive Folders and Files. If it is possible please send information for how to connect and how to access. Otherwise if it is not possible send Reason. Please reply your comments are valuable me. Thanks.

Comment: copy the file/folders from your pen drive to emulator SDcard.

Comment: how to copy the file/folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//its possible

open your `eclipse->show view->android->choose file explorer`

push your file to SDcard now

Comment: Thanks Thanks. It's work fine. But how to access files/folders directly in the pen drive to emulator(do not copy files/folders). If it's possible.

Comment: @Bala here is no way for the Anrdoid emulator to access your hard drive.

Comment: @Bala its little difficult for you to do need to mount your SDcard.img and put files and then unmount it again: http://www.jayway.com/2009/04/22/working-with-sd-cards-in-the-android-emulator/

Comment: Thanks Your information all are very useful to me. I saw that website. Here got some useful tips. Here using Linux comments. I used windows 7. How to change that comments, any idea.